# Regex not working accurately in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to C# and working with regular expressions. I have created a regex accurately and have tested online but when I use that regex in my function it always validate it as success case.

Here is my code:

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"[+]?[0-9]+");
        Match match = regex.Match(phone);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

and I am using this number to validate : +92-322-4995562 which must be invalid according to my regex but it is returning me as match case. Please help

Comment: try `^[+]?[0-9]+$` or `^\+?\d+$`

Comment: What's "match.Groups[1].Value"?

Comment: @User2012384 => {+92}. Problem solved.

Comment: Oh yes, he forgot ^ $...

Comment: Hi @Tim007 , thanks for your quick response. Its working fine now. Can you please tell me why we have added ^ and +$ at the end?

Comment: @Bilal Amjad check my answer

Comment: **`\+?\d+`** can match `+92` or `322` or `4995562` with  global/all matches. **`^\+?\d+`** only match `+92` because `^` assert position at start of a line. **`\+?\d+$`** only match `4995562` because `$` assert position at end of a line.  **`^\+?\d+$`** not match `+92-322-4995562` but match entire `+923224995562`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
`^[+]?[0-9]+$` or `^\+?\d+$`

Explanation:
`^` assert position at start of the string
`\+` matches the character `+`
`\d` match a digit [0-9]
`$` assert position at end of the string

Comment: What matches the `-`?

Comment: `-` must be invalid according to @Bilal Amjad regex

Comment: `^\+?[\d-]+$` this one will allow `-`

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question properly

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't wrong because you're not anchoring the pattern.

This allows the regex engine to find a position *inside* the input where the pattern matches, and not be forced to check if the *entire* input matches.

Specifically, this pattern:

```
[+]?[0-9]+
```

Matches this part:

```
+92-322-4995562
^^^
```

To ensure it checks against the whole input you must "anchor" it by specifying that the start of the pattern has to coincide with the start of the input, and that the end of the pattern has to coincide with the end of the input.

You do this with a pattern like this:

```
^....$
```

The `^` character anchors to the start of the input and `$` to the end of the input.

So your final pattern should look like this:

```
^[+]?[0-9]+$
```